# Alternative to CSOM ListItem.get_item

Tags: javascript, splistitem, client-object-model, splist

The only way I know to load a sharepoint list via Javascript is to load it and on the current list item:

```
var value = currentItem.get_item(columnTitle);
```

I want to be able to load an item and on the fly populate a JavaScript Object:

```
ListName.Field = Value;
```

so I need a way to iterate through the currentItem and get the Column Title + its Value. The only way I can think of doing that is first by loading the field names and doing it that way, but is there a native way of retreiving all fields from a listitem?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the collection of "field_name + field_value", you can try:

```
var fieldValues = currentItem.get_fieldValues();
```

It returns an object, the object key is field name and the object value is field value.